# utf8mb4 setting for talend - not working

Tags: mysql, sql-server, talend

I am migrating the data from sql server to mysql. I am using the tool Talend(ETL) for the same.

The problem comes when I have emojis in the source (sql server) , it does not get inserted to the table in mysql. So, I know I must use utf8mb4 on mysql side.

The client settings character encoding has to be set, for the smileys to get inserted. The database, tables and the server are all on utf8mb4

But, the client i.e., talend is not utf8mb4. So where do I set this?

I tried with 'set names utf8mb4' in additional parameters of tmysqloutput. But this does not work

I have been stuck on this for days, any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Update :

The job looks like this now. But, the smileys are still getting exported as **'?'**

[image]

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: Could you please share your MySQL Server config file ? not all of it, but just any parameter that has character-set or collation-server in its name : default-character-set, character-set-server, ..etc

Comment: Any update on your problem ?

Comment: Hi iMezouar, I will update soon on the test cases I'm running with your solution

Answer (score 1):

First, make sur that your server is properly configured to use utf8mb4.
Following this [tutorial](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4), you need to add the following to your my.cnf (or my.ini if you're on Windows):

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

That tells MySQL server to use utf8mb4 and ignore any encoding set by client.
After that, I didn't need to do set any additional properties on the MySQL connection in Talend. I've executed this query in Talend to check the encoding set by it :

```
SHOW VARIABLES 
WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\\_set\\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%'
```

And it returned:

```
|=-----------------------+-----------------=|
|Variable_Name           |Value             |
|=-----------------------+-----------------=|
|character_set_client    |utf8mb4           |
|character_set_connection|utf8mb4           |
|character_set_database  |utf8mb4           |
|character_set_filesystem|binary            |
|character_set_results   |                  |
|character_set_server    |utf8mb4           |
|character_set_system    |utf8              |
|collation_connection    |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
|collation_database      |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
|collation_server        |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
'------------------------+------------------'
```

The following test to insert a pile of poop works:

[image]

[image]

**Update**

Using native MySQL components in Talend 6.3.1, you get `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`, which is supposed to automatically detect the utf8mb4 used by the server, but for some reason (bug?) it isn't doing that.
I switched to using JDBC components, and downloaded the latest mysql [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474258) (`mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar`), I got it working by setting these additional parameters on the `tJDBCConnection` component :

```
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

(even if I'm specifying utf-8, the doc says it will treat it as utf8mb4)

Here's what my job looks like now :

[image]

Comment: Thank you iMezouar. I understand the settings I must make in the my.cnf file. However, I cannot make these changes as my mysql is hosted on Amazon RDS and have no access to my.cnf file. This is the reason I was trying to make it work using the set names utf8mb4

Comment: Could you please post what `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name like 'char%'` returns ?
The documentation clearly states that issuing a set names command with jdbc connector doesn't work.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html
> Warning
> Do not issue the query set names with Connector/J, as the driver will not detect that the character set has changed, and will continue to use the character set detected during the initial connection setup.

Comment: hi iMezouar, the results of SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name like 'char%' are as follows character_set_client = utf8,character_set_connection = utf8,character_set_database = utf8mb4, character_set_filesystem =binary, character_set_results = utf8, character_set_server = utf8mb4,character_set_system = utf8

Comment: Hi iMezouar, Apologies for the delayed response. I'm trying to do with tmssqlnput and tmysqlputput, how do I use your answer with these 2? I am unable to connect them

Comment: No problem. You can simple replace tFixedFlowInput in my exemple with a tMSSqlInput (and a tMap so you can have more flexibility)

Comment: Thank you iMezouar. But, in the tjdbcconnection should'nt I specify sql server connection details and not the mysql connection details?

Comment: tJDBCConnection is used to connect to MySQL (and is used by tJDBCOutput) as I did in my example. You need to add a tMSSqlConnection to connect to SQL Server and use it in tMSSqlInput

Comment: Hi iMezouar, I have done the changes as per your suggestion. The job details , I have updated in the main question. I still can't get the emoticons exported

Comment: That is not what I suggested, what worked for me was tJDBC components not tMysql, did you try with that ?? (The updated part of my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166291/discussion-between-rathi-rao-and-imezouar).

Comment: Hi iMezouar, how do I use tjdbc with tmssqlinput? I'm unable to figure that out. sql server to mysql it is, so I use tmssqlconnection & tmssqlinput, so where do I out the tjdbc here?

Comment: Hi iMezouar, the new mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar does not allow me to connect to the mysql database. Is there any other setting I must do?

Comment: Hi iMezouar, I got the driver to work. However, the emoticon is still a ? in mysql, even after the change in the driver. I have updated the changes in my question

Comment: Hi iMezouar, the tmssqlinput gives the output as a smiley, its the tjdbcinput not considering it