# TALEND - Vagrant Mysql connexion issues

Tags: mysql, vagrant, talend

I'm pulling my hair over the following situation.

I'm unable to connect to my MySQL server in Vagrant (2.0.0 , OS: Ubuntu 16.04 ) with only specific applications (HeidiSQL and Talend 6.1). 
This error happens with Talend MySQL components with the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30 jar` and `Java 1.8 JRE`.

I receive the following error each time when connecting either directly (TCP/IP) or over SSH (TCP/IP over SSH) to the MySQL Server with the aforementionned applications:

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'IP' (using password: YES)
```

This however doesn't happens with MysqlWorkbench with both direct connection (TCP/IP) or over SSH with the same user credentials.  Below are the settings of the MySQL server:
`MySQL Server Network Info 
 Maria Db: 10.0.34 
 bind-address: 0.0.0.0
 skip-name-resolve: true`

The following have already been tried and tested:

- Access credentials and privileges verification
- DNS flush both on Guest and Host machines
- Addition of MySQL server IP to host file
- Verification of ports opening both on host and guest

Comment: Seems like a JDBC specific issue. What version of Talend are you using ? And the mysql jdbc driver ? Are you using tMysql* components ?

Comment: Updated my question with the required info

Comment: It's a long (long) shot, but could you please try with JDBC components in Talend, with the latest MySQL JDBC jar ? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html
Please see this answer on how to configure JDBC to connect to MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984828/utf8mb4-setting-for-talend-not-working/48991770#48991770 (last part of the answer)

Comment: I'm unable to update the JAR when i do change it always revert in the GUI to the 5.1.30 connector JAR . Do you have a step on updating it ?

Comment: On a tJDBC* component, when you click the + on "Driver JAR" list, it creates a "newLine" entry; you then click on the 3 dots to browse your jar, select "External modules", and browse the jar on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the help . The new JAR didn't change the error . However , granting privileges with 'GRANT OPTION' to the user did the trick . Im still dumbfounded as to why.

Comment: Yep, that's MySQL for you ! I believe the best thing to do is to post an answer with the solution and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the issue:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH **GRANT OPTION**;
```

The **`GRANT OPTION`** does the trick.

Alternatively this  could be caused by wrong driver being used in your Talend workspace. To update the MySQL connector JAR follow the steps below:

1. Donwload the updated connector driver [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)
2. Replace the 'tMySQLOutput/tMySQLInput' component(s) with an equivalent tJDBC ones
3. Add the new connector JAR (No 2 on the image) and the class name **`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`** (No 4 on the image) (ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html)

[image]